# How do I use javascript from content loaded with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, accordion

I have done a lot of researching in other questions and on Google, and so far nothing has worked. I have some JavaScript/jQuery experience and consider myself fluent in PHP.

I am developing an app for work that uses jQuery to load pages from the navigation menu. Here is the setup of that element so far:

```
<menu>
    <button value="home">HOME</button>
    <button value="process_sheets">PROCESS SHEETS</button>
    <button value="admin">ADMINISTRATION</button>
    <button value="faq">FAQ</button>
    <div id="search-container"></div>
</menu>

<script>

$("menu button").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        $.get(null, {
            page: $(this).val()
        }, function(data) {
            $("article#content").html($.parseHTML(data));
        }, 'html');
    });
});

</script>
```

The problem is that I have a simple accordion on one page that has code that isn't working when loaded through the menu.

Here is the accordion code:

```
$(function($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
        $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    });
});

<h2>Process Sheets</h2>
<div id="process-sheets-accordion">
    <h4 class="accordion-toggle">GE</h4>
    <div class="accordion-content">
<?php include 'static_section_form.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <h4 class="accordion-toggle">5"</h4>
    <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
    </div>
    etc...
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like you're loading jquery on the same page it should be loaded after your `particular page` loads

Comment: There's no purpose whatsoever to the `$.parseHTML` part of this: `$("article#content").html($.parseHTML(data));`

Comment: @Justcode no luck :(

Comment: @T.J.Crowder still didn't fix...

Comment: @CoreyRay: I didn't say that would fix it, just that it's pointless. So is the `article` part of `$("article#content")`, unless the element type of your `#content` element may change from one page load to the next and you only want to use it when it's an `article`, which is pretty unlikely. Moreover, using `$("article#content")` is markedly slower than simply `$("#content")`.

Comment: In your second code snippet, you are querying the DOM for an element with an id of `accordion`, i.e. `$('#accordion') ...`. But I don't see any such element in your HTML. 

There is a parent element with an id of `process-sheets-accordion`. Is that what you meant to query for instead?

Comment: @CoreyRay can you check console for any errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code in question is actually in the text returned by the ajax call, the problem is that that doesn't get executed when you load via `get` and then parse it and add it to the page.

jQuery has a function specifically designed for doing exactly that, though: [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$("menu button").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        $("article#content").load(null, {page: $(this).val()});
    });
});
```

`load` will retrieve the page using ajax, extract the scripts from it, put the content into the element, and then execute the scripts.

The above would use POST because we're passing an object as the second argument, but as you're using GET, we should just add `page` to the URL:

```
$("article#content").load(location.pathname + "?page=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val()));
```

...or by passing it as a string:

```
$("article#content").load(location.pathname, "page=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val()));
```

If you don't give a data object, `load` defaults to GET instead of POST.

---

Side note: I've never seen `null` as the URL for `$.get` before. I've copied it to the `load` call above, but I don't think `null` is valid (in either place), as there's nothing in the documentation saying it can be anything but a string. Use an actual URL, such as the `location.pathname` I've used in the GET example above.

Comment: Now the pages do not load. The null value causes .get it to default to the current url. I need that functionality as well if possible.

Comment: @CoreyRay: That's not documented behavior, and so could break in a dot rev (e.g., it may work in v1.11.1 but fail in v1.11.2). And indeed, it could well be that it works with `$.get` but not with `load`. It's incorrect in any case, so it needs fixing. Use a real URL and `load` should work.

Comment: ok, let me throw in a php call to get the requested url and I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @CoreyRay: PHP? What does that have to do with knowing in client-side code what the current URL is? `window.location`.

Comment: I am more familiar with PHP, however I did look that up first. Using window.location.pathname. It looks like load uses a post request, how can I change it to a get request without modifying my API?

Comment: Oh and the documented behavior is from the .ajax function that .get is shorthand for.

Comment: @CoreyRay: Ah, yes, sorry, it uses POST if you pass an object as the second argument. You can make it use GET by not doing that, just appending `page` to the URL: `$("article#content").load(location.pathname + "?page=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val()));`

Comment: @CoreyRay: Re `url`: There's a difference between not supplying the option *at all* and supplying `null`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67108/discussion-between-corey-ray-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: @CoreyRay: I don't do the chat thing if it relates to the question/answer. (And apologies, too busy to just chat if it doesn't. :-) )

Comment: Got it. Thank you though. Ill mark this as answered. Stack Overflow asked me politely to move multiple comments to chat. My apologies.

Comment: @CoreyRay: Not your fault, it's one of SO's dumber "features." :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working snippet of code which does exactly as I intended:

```
$("menu button").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load(window.location.pathname + "?page=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val()));
    });
});
```